# systemd-boot doesn't detect Windows

Tags: dual-boot, boot-loader, systemd-boot, pop-os

I recently installed **Pop!_OS** alongside with **Windows 10** (installed **Win10** first) and my problem is that when i boot into **PopOS** it doesn't detect **Windows 10** as a boot option, it directly boots into **PopOS** (neither does **Windows 10 boot manager** detect **PopOS** when it boots). when i run `sudo bootctl` it shows this:

```
   Setup Mode: user
 Boot into FW: supported

Current Boot Loader:
      Product: systemd-boot 245.4-4ubuntu3.2pop1~1596049172~20.04~c9d8f2b
     Features: ✓ Boot counting
               ✓ Menu timeout control
               ✓ One-shot menu timeout control
               ✓ Default entry control
               ✓ One-shot entry control
               ✓ Support for XBOOTLDR partition
               ✓ Support for passing random seed to OS
               ✓ Boot loader sets ESP partition information
          ESP: /dev/disk/by-partuuid/84985ed5-9476-4fad-81e1-67d4d51ca484
         File: └─/EFI/systemd/systemd-bootx64.efi

Random Seed:
 Passed to OS: yes
 System Token: set
       Exists: yes
vailable Boot Loaders on ESP:
          ESP: /boot/efi (/dev/disk/by-partuuid/84985ed5-9476-4fad-81e1-67d4d51>
         File: └─/EFI/systemd/systemd-bootx64.efi (systemd-boot 245.4-4ubuntu3.>
         File: └─/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI (systemd-boot 245.4-4ubuntu3.2pop1~15960>

Boot Loaders Listed in EFI Variables:
        Title: Pop!_OS 20.04 LTS
           ID: 0x0005
       Status: active, boot-order
    Partition: /dev/disk/by-partuuid/84985ed5-9476-4fad-81e1-67d4d51ca484
         File: └─/EFI/systemd/systemd-bootx64.efi

        Title: Windows Boot Manager
           ID: 0x0004
       Status: active, boot-order
    Partition: /dev/disk/by-partuuid/ae50c936-d1de-4de7-a533-791e4e782158
         File: └─/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
 Firmware: UEFI 2.40 (INSYDE Corp. 3894.00)
  Secure Boot: disabled
   Setup Mode: user
 Boot into FW: supported

Current Boot Loader:
      Product: systemd-boot 245.4-4ubuntu3.2pop1~1596049172~20.04~c9d8f2b
     Features: ✓ Boot counting
               ✓ Menu timeout control
               ✓ One-shot menu timeout control
               ✓ Default entry control
               ✓ One-shot entry control
               ✓ Support for XBOOTLDR partition
               ✓ Support for passing random seed to OS
               ✓ Boot loader sets ESP partition information
          ESP: /dev/disk/by-partuuid/84985ed5-9476-4fad-81e1-67d4d51ca484
         File: └─/EFI/systemd/systemd-bootx64.efi

Random Seed:
 Passed to OS: yes
 System Token: set
       Exists: yes
vailable Boot Loaders on ESP:
          ESP: /boot/efi (/dev/disk/by-partuuid/84985ed5-9476-4fad-81e1-67d4d51>
         File: └─/EFI/systemd/systemd-bootx64.efi (systemd-boot 245.4-4ubuntu3.>
         File: └─/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI (systemd-boot 245.4-4ubuntu3.2pop1~15960>

Boot Loaders Listed in EFI Variables:
        Title: Pop!_OS 20.04 LTS
           ID: 0x0005
       Status: active, boot-order
    Partition: /dev/disk/by-partuuid/84985ed5-9476-4fad-81e1-67d4d51ca484
         File: └─/EFI/systemd/systemd-bootx64.efi

        Title: Windows Boot Manager
           ID: 0x0004
       Status: active, boot-order
    Partition: /dev/disk/by-partuuid/ae50c936-d1de-4de7-a533-791e4e782158
         File: └─/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
```

`sudo bootctl list` shows:

```
Boot Loader Entries:
        title: Pop!_OS (Pop_OS-current.conf) (default)
           id: Pop_OS-current.conf
       source: /boot/efi/loader/entries/Pop_OS-current.conf
        linux: /EFI/Pop_OS-795ab9be-5801-40c1-bc73-7e883658c4db/vmlinuz.efi
       initrd: /EFI/Pop_OS-795ab9be-5801-40c1-bc73-7e883658c4db/initrd.img
      options: root=UUID=795ab9be-5801-40c1-bc73-7e883658c4db ro quiet loglevel>

        title: Pop!_OS (Pop_OS-oldkern.conf)
           id: Pop_OS-oldkern.conf
       source: /boot/efi/loader/entries/Pop_OS-oldkern.conf
        linux: /EFI/Pop_OS-795ab9be-5801-40c1-bc73-7e883658c4db/vmlinuz-previou>
       initrd: /EFI/Pop_OS-795ab9be-5801-40c1-bc73-7e883658c4db/initrd.img-prev>
      options: root=UUID=795ab9be-5801-40c1-bc73-7e883658c4db ro quiet loglevel>

        title: pop_os-current.conf
           id: pop_os-current.conf
       source: /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/LoaderEntries-4a67b082-0a4c-41cf-b6c7->

        title: pop_os-oldkern.conf
           id: pop_os-oldkern.conf
       source: /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/LoaderEntries-4a67b082-0a4c-41cf-b6c7->

       title: Reboot Into Firmware Interface
           id: auto-reboot-to-firmware-setup
       source: /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/LoaderEntries-4a67b082-0a4c-41cf-b6c7-
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Have you set a menu timeout in `/boot/efi/loader/loader.conf`?

Comment: @JohanMyréen yes i did

Comment: I asked because you said it directly boots into PopOS. So the menu *is* displayed, and Windows is missing from it?

Comment: @JohanMyréen exactly